# Importing plugins in models

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a model which imports `@ionic/storage` for reading and writing key/value pairs.

Accoding to the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/) I have to put the storage in the constructor of my model: `constructor(private storage: Storage)`

Here is the issue. I'm importing my model in some of my pages, and when I want to create a new instance of my model I have to pass a `Storage` to my model, that means I also have to import `@ionic/storage` in each page that creates instances of my model.

My page does not use `Storage`, that is only my model. Is there a smarter way so it's only neccecary to import `Storage` in my model?

Comment: The model should not store values in the storage. That should be done from a provider instead.

Comment: To understand this right, I create a service which does the storage part. Then I use my service within my model?

Comment: Not really because you'd need to inject the service in the model in that case. Could you please add some more code so we can understand in what scenario should the model be saved in the storage?

Comment: My model is a "Timer" which is starting at example 10 seconds and then counts down 1 second, each second and updates its string property which is shown to the user. The storage part is when the model is instantiated it's getting a specific preference from the user.

Comment: So in that case you should use a service to get that value from the storage, and that service should also initialize the timer. If you want, please add the most relevant parts of the code, so we can work on that, it'd be easier to explain

Comment: I've read up on providers and made a global provider that gets the user preference and interacts with the timers, this has really cleaned up my code a lot, Thank you.

Comment: So glad to hear that :) Could you please post that as an answer (maybe with a few lines of code)? It may help some other SO users :)